# How to get value of a command line argument in C

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, command-line-arguments

I am writing a program in which I need to get the value of the second command line argument to later determine what algorithm to use.

Command line argument: $ ./project2 FIRSTFIT 268435456 testfile.txt

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
//~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Main
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    /*
     Reading in the parameters from command line
     argv[0] = the program
     argv[1] = the type of memory allocation algorithm to use
     argv[2] = N = total memory allocation
     argv[3] = script file (.txt)
     */
    char* memAlgoType = (char*)argv[1];
    int totalMemAlloc = atoi(argv[2]);
    FILE* file;
    file = fopen(argv[3], "r");
    
//~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ First fit
    if(strcmp(memAlgoType, "FIRSTFIT") == 0)
    {
        //code for first fit algorithm here
    }
}
```

When I do this, I get segmentation faults (core dump) errors and on my XCode IDE, I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error when I use strcmp()

I have tried revising my code to `char memAlgoType = (char)argv[1][0];` to only compare the first characters
I have tried `strcpy(memAlgoType, argv[1])` and also tried the  `memcpy()` method as well. All of which give me segmentation faults.

Comment: You should check `argc` before trying to use `argv`.

Comment: The errors you're getting would happen if you don't actually pass the command line arguments.

Comment: Your program works fine for me (when I add the missing close brace).  Is this the full program you are testing with?  If not, the bug could be in the part you left out; a [mcve] is essential in such cases.

Comment: You probably don't have any command line arguments when you run directly from XCode IDE

Answer (score 0):

Check with `argc` if all arguments are provided.

NOTE: `int totalMemAlloc = atoi(argv[2]);` can be dangerous with large numbers.

Comment: to check argc, would I just do an if statement to see if argc > 0?

Comment: No, you need to check if a user has provided enough arguments. argc > 0 checks if a user provides at least 1 argument.

Comment: argc > 0 checks if a user provides at least 0 arguments.